# find the user's geo location in android phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, gps, geolocation

I am developing android apps in phonegap in that apps i want to find the location of my people or user's. I have email id's of gmail and mobile number of user's using that info is there is way to find out the location of user's. I tired some code from phonegap documentation but I don't understand how it is work? 
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

it works exactly as stated in [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html).

```
var onSuccess = function(position) {
        alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
            'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
            'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
            'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
            'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
            'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
            'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
            'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
    };


    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
            'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

Remember to do this AFTER deviceready event has fired.

Comment: here i don't understand how above code will return location of user's but i am not passing any parameter like emails , address and etc

Comment: You will have to use the code above and send the data (after user's approval) to the server. From there you can view and handle the location data of your users. You can even view that data from within the app, but you will need a central place where all comes together (or write a P2P protocol for it).

Comment: I run the code above it giving me latitude ,longitude of my device but  from your above comment you said send data to the server what this mean? how can send data to the server? please give me some resources for doing this above task.

Comment: one thing is here I want to find the location of multiple user's at time when i click on get user's location tab then location list will occour.

Comment: Every user will have to upload it's location to a central database. That central database can then be read by you. This is the only way. The API of PhoneGap does not support getting the location of another device on which the app is installed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use geolocation cordova plugin

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation

Documentation here:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/blob/master/doc/index.md

Use this code to identify current user location.

```
// onSuccess Callback
// This method accepts a Position object, which contains the
// current GPS coordinates
//
var onSuccess = function(position) {
    alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
          'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
          'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
          'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
          'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
          'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
          'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
          'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
};

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```